# jQuery error with datepicker() code

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using this code from here:

```
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
```

I put this code on my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
     $( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker();
     $( "#datepicker4" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

In the Firefox firebug console, I see this error:

```
 TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

the #datepicker pulls the field tag into it. Why does it say that datepicker() is not a function? if I have the rest of the code above it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/dateTimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
<script src="/css/dateTimepicker/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/css/dateTimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .custom-date-style {    background-color: red !important; }
</style>
```

I have put that code above it and below it and it does not matter. That error is always there.

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Also, I do use other scripts that pull in jQuery, and have a jquery.js file.

Could they be causing a conflict?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: First of all, you missed `});` at the end of script. Secondly, are you sure that _/css/dateTimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js_ is correct way (why JS file is in CSS directory and why it is "datetimepicker.js", not "datepicker.js")?

Comment: I just uploaded it into the css folder on my site. I know that is not where I should put js files, but I just uploaded the whole thing in to there.

The datetimepicker.js is from the example I found on that website. and that is the file I uploaded to. I did not change it to that.

Comment: Yes, the script tags are there, opening and closing.

Comment: hmm, okay, I'm not a jQuery guru guy, what is jQuery UI? my bad, I don't know.

Comment: It's not about jQuery guru, it's about including additional script. Add `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` **between** jQuery and datepicker scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You missing curly braces:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: My bad, I only copied it from the error... I edited it to have the whole section in my source code: